# Ask an optimization problem

Tags: optimization

Consider $x,y,z$ are $n$-dimensional variables, and $a,b,c$ are three nonnegative vectors.

Let $f(x,y,z)=a^T x+b^T y+c^T z-\left(\|x\|_2^{2/3}+\|y\|_2^{2/3}+\|z\|_2^{2/3}\right)^3$. 
How to find the maximum of $f(x,y,z)$ over $x,y,z\ge 0$?

Comment: Did you compute the optimality conditions? You intend to do numerical computations?

Comment: The $L_2$ seems to be a norm for functions, while $x,y,z$ are $n$-vectors. Maybe you mean the 2-norm, thus the Euclidean distance?

Comment: Is there any partial convexity ? I mean can the feasible domain break into some intervals in which the OF is convex ?

Comment: @mvw I mean the Euclidean distance to the origin, that is $||x||_2=\sqrt{x_1^2+\cdots+x_n^2}$.

Comment: @BeniBogosel I just want to find an algorithm (e.g. iterative algorithm) to obtain the maximum of the function $f$, as we do in the quadratic optimization problems.

Comment: @Cardinal I have no idea. If we could do so, how should we do next? Choose an initial point in each subregion?

Answer (score 2):

Here is my attempt:
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} f =
a_i - 3 \left(
\lVert x\rVert_2^{2/3} + 
\lVert y\rVert_2^{2/3} + 
\lVert z\rVert_2^{2/3}
\right)^2 
\frac{2 x_i}{3\lVert x \rVert_2^{4/3}}
$$
We have critical points for
$$
0 = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} f =
a -  
\frac{2 \left(
\lVert x\rVert_2^{2/3} + 
\lVert y\rVert_2^{2/3} + 
\lVert z\rVert_2^{2/3}
\right)^2}{\lVert x \rVert_2^{4/3}} x
= a - \lambda x 
\\
0 = \frac{\partial}{\partial y} f =
b -  
\frac{2 \left(
\lVert x\rVert_2^{2/3} + 
\lVert y\rVert_2^{2/3} + 
\lVert z\rVert_2^{2/3}
\right)^2}{\lVert y \rVert_2^{4/3}} y 
= b - \mu y 
\\
0 =\frac{\partial}{\partial z} f =
c -  
\frac{2 \left(
\lVert x\rVert_2^{2/3} + 
\lVert y\rVert_2^{2/3} + 
\lVert z\rVert_2^{2/3}
\right)^2}{\lVert z \rVert_2^{4/3}} z
= c - \nu z
$$
for some non-negative numbers $\lambda, \mu, \nu$.

If $a=0$ then $x=0$, if $b=0$ then $y=0$ and if $c=0$ then $z=0$.
Otherwise choose from below for the non-zero $a, b, c$ cases:

\begin{align}
x &= \alpha\, a \quad (\alpha = 1 / \lambda > 0) \\
y &= \beta\, b  \quad (\beta = 1 / \mu > 0) \\
z &= \gamma\, c  \quad (\gamma = 1 / \nu > 0) \\
\end{align}
This leads to up to three equations in the real unknowns $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$:
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{\alpha} &=
\frac{2 \left(
\lVert \alpha a \rVert_2^{2/3} + 
\lVert \beta b \rVert_2^{2/3} + 
\lVert \gamma c \rVert_2^{2/3}
\right)^2}{\lVert \alpha a \rVert_2^{4/3}} \\
&=
\frac{2 \left(
\alpha^{2/3} \lVert a \rVert_2^{2/3} + 
\beta^{2/3} \lVert  b \rVert_2^{2/3} + 
\gamma^{2/3} \lVert  c \rVert_2^{2/3}
\right)^2}{\alpha^{4/3} \lVert a \rVert_2^{4/3}} \iff \\
\alpha^{1/3} \lVert a \rVert_2^{4/3} &=
2 \left(
\alpha^{2/3} \lVert a \rVert_2^{2/3} + 
\beta^{2/3} \lVert  b \rVert_2^{2/3} + 
\gamma^{2/3} \lVert  c \rVert_2^{2/3}
\right)^2
\end{align}
which is equivalent to
\begin{align}
2^{1/2} \left(
\lVert a \rVert_2^{2/3} \alpha^{2/3} + 
\lVert b \rVert_2^{2/3} \beta^{2/3} + 
\lVert c \rVert_2^{2/3} \gamma^{2/3} 
\right) 
&= \lVert a \rVert_2^{2/3} \alpha^{1/6} \quad (*) \\
&= \lVert b \rVert_2^{2/3} \beta^{1/6} \\
&= \lVert c \rVert_2^{2/3} \gamma^{1/6}
\end{align}

**Example:** For non-zero $a, b, c$ the RHS give
$$
\lVert a \rVert_2^4 \alpha =
\lVert b \rVert_2^4 \beta =
\lVert c \rVert_2^4 \gamma
$$
Expressing $\beta$ and $\gamma$ in terms of $\alpha$ in $(*)$ gives
\begin{align}
2^{1/2} \left(
\lVert a \rVert_2^{2/3} + 
\lVert b \rVert_2^{2/3} \left( 
\frac{\lVert a \rVert_2}{\lVert b \rVert_2}
\right)^{8/3} +
\lVert c \rVert_2^{2/3} \left( 
\frac{\lVert a \rVert_2}{\lVert c \rVert_2}
\right)^{8/3}
\right) \alpha^{2/3}
&= \lVert a \rVert_2^{2/3} \alpha^{1/6} \iff \\
2^{1/2} \left(
1 + 
\frac{\lVert b \rVert_2^{2/3}}{\lVert a \rVert_2^{2/3}} 
\left( 
\frac{\lVert a \rVert_2}{\lVert b \rVert_2}
\right)^{8/3} +
\frac{\lVert c \rVert_2^{2/3}}{\lVert a \rVert_2^{2/3}} 
\left( 
\frac{\lVert a \rVert_2}{\lVert c \rVert_2}
\right)^{8/3}
\right) \alpha^{1/2}
&= 1 \iff \\
2^{1/2} \left(
1 +   
\frac{\lVert a \rVert_2^2}{\lVert b \rVert_2^2} +
\frac{\lVert a \rVert_2^2}{\lVert c \rVert_2^2}
\right) \alpha^{1/2}
&= 1 \iff \\
\alpha =
\frac{\lVert b \rVert_2^4 \, \lVert c \rVert_2^4}
{
2 \left(
\lVert b \rVert_2^2\, \lVert c \rVert_2^2 +
\lVert a \rVert_2^2\, \lVert c \rVert_2^2 +
\lVert a \rVert_2^2\, \lVert b \rVert_2^2
\right)^2
}
\\
\beta =
\frac{\lVert a \rVert_2^4 \, \lVert c \rVert_2^4}
{
2 \left(
\lVert b \rVert_2^2\, \lVert c \rVert_2^2 +
\lVert a \rVert_2^2\, \lVert c \rVert_2^2 +
\lVert a \rVert_2^2\, \lVert b \rVert_2^2
\right)^2
}
\\
\gamma =
\frac{\lVert a \rVert_2^4 \, \lVert b \rVert_2^4}
{
2 \left(
\lVert b \rVert_2^2\, \lVert c \rVert_2^2 +
\lVert a \rVert_2^2\, \lVert c \rVert_2^2 +
\lVert a \rVert_2^2\, \lVert b \rVert_2^2
\right)^2
}
\end{align}

The maximum is: 
\begin{align}
f(\alpha\, a, \beta\, b, \gamma\, c)
&= 
\alpha\, \lVert a \rVert_2^2 +
\beta\,  \lVert b \rVert_2^2 +
\gamma\, \lVert c \rVert_2^2
-
\left( 
\lVert \alpha a \rVert_2^{2/3} + 
\lVert \beta b \rVert_2^{2/3} +
\lVert \gamma c \rVert_2^{2/3}
\right)^3 
\\
&= 
\alpha\, \lVert a \rVert_2^2 +
\beta\,  \lVert b \rVert_2^2 +
\gamma\, \lVert c \rVert_2^2
-
\left( 
\lVert a \rVert_2^{2/3} \alpha^{2/3}  + 
\lVert b \rVert_2^{2/3} \beta^{2/3}  +
\lVert c \rVert_2^{2/3} \gamma^{2/3} 
\right)^3 
\\
&= 
\alpha\, \lVert a \rVert_2^2 +
\beta\,  \lVert b \rVert_2^2 +
\gamma\, \lVert c \rVert_2^2
-
\left( 
\frac{1}{2^{1/2}} \lVert a \rVert_2^{2/3} \alpha^{1/6}
\right)^3
\\
&= 
\alpha\, \lVert a \rVert_2^2 +
\beta\,  \lVert b \rVert_2^2 +
\gamma\, \lVert c \rVert_2^2
-
\frac{1}{2^{3/2}} \lVert a \rVert_2^{2} \alpha^{1/2}
\\
&= 
\lVert a \rVert_2^2 \alpha +
\frac{\lVert a \rVert_2^4}{\lVert b \rVert_2^2} \alpha +
\frac{\lVert a \rVert_2^4}{\lVert c \rVert_2^2} \alpha
-
\frac{1}{2^{3/2}} \lVert a \rVert_2^{2} \alpha^{1/2}
\\
&= 
\lVert a \rVert_2^2 \alpha 
\left( 
1 +
\frac{\lVert a \rVert_2^2}{\lVert b \rVert_2^2} +
\frac{\lVert a \rVert_2^2}{\lVert c \rVert_2^2}
\right)
-
\frac{1}{2^{3/2}} \lVert a \rVert_2^{2} \alpha^{1/2}
\\
&= 
\lVert a \rVert_2^2 \alpha 
\frac{
\lVert b \rVert_2^2 \, \lVert c \rVert_2^2 +
\lVert a \rVert_2^2 \, \lVert c \rVert_2^2 +
\lVert a \rVert_2^2 \, \lVert b \rVert_2^2
}{\lVert b \rVert_2^2 \, \lVert c \rVert_2^2}
-
\frac{1}{2^{3/2}} \lVert a \rVert_2^{2} \alpha^{1/2}
\\
&= 
\lVert a \rVert_2^2 \alpha 
\frac{1}{(2a)^{1/2}}
-
\frac{1}{2^{3/2}} \lVert a \rVert_2^{2} \alpha^{1/2}
\\
&= \frac{7}{8\, 2^{1/2}} \lVert a \rVert_2^{2} \alpha^{1/2} \\
&= \frac{7}{16} 
\frac{\lVert a \rVert_2^{2} \, \lVert b \rVert_2^2 \, \lVert c \rVert_2^2}
{
\lVert b \rVert_2^2\, \lVert c \rVert_2^2 +
\lVert a \rVert_2^2\, \lVert c \rVert_2^2 +
\lVert a \rVert_2^2\, \lVert b \rVert_2^2
}
\end{align}

**Example:** E.g. $a \ne 0$, $b = c = 0$:

$$
f(x,y,z) = a^T x - 
\left(
\lVert x\rVert_2^{2/3} + 
\lVert y\rVert_2^{2/3} + 
\lVert z\rVert_2^{2/3}
\right)^3
$$
It seems reasonable that $y = z = 0$ for a maximum, otherwise they would decrease the value of $f$.

So we continue maximizing
$$
f(x,0,0) = a^T x - 
\lVert x\rVert_2^2 \quad (**)
$$
From the above we assume $x = \alpha a$ and use equation $(*)$ without the terms in $\beta, b, \gamma, c$ and have
$$
2^{1/2} \lVert a \rVert_2^{2/3} \alpha^{2/3} 
= \lVert a \rVert_2^{2/3} \alpha^{1/6} \iff \\
2^{1/2} \alpha^{2/3} 
= \alpha^{1/6} \iff \\
2 \alpha^{4/3} = \alpha^{1/3} \iff \\
\alpha = \frac{1}{2}
$$
which is what we would get from analyzing equation $(**)$.

The maximum is: 
$$
f((1/2)a,0,0) = \frac{1}{4} \lVert a \rVert_2^2
$$